# Add days to business day calendar in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to add days to a business day calendar. Somehow I should receive the date 28.04.2015 but using my code I am getting 24.04.2015. I am using holiday calender and only weekdays (Monday to Friday). The code looks like the following:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date    
import holidays

def getNextBusinessDays(date, num):
    for i in range(0, num):
        date = getNextBusinessDay(date)
    return date    

def getNextBusinessDay(fromDate):

    Holiday = holidays.DE()

    nextBuinessDate = datetime.strptime(fromDate, "%Y-%m-%d")
    nextBuinessDate = nextBuinessDate + timedelta(days=1) 
    if date.weekday(nextBuinessDate) not in range(0, 5) and nextBuinessDate not in Holiday:
        nextBuinessDate = nextBuinessDate + timedelta(days=1)
    if date.weekday(nextBuinessDate) not in range(0, 5) and nextBuinessDate not in Holiday:
        nextBuinessDate = nextBuinessDate + timedelta(days=1)
    return nextBuinessDate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    dateshift = getNextBusinessDays('2015-02-01', 60)
    print(dateshift)
```

Comment: can you post your complete code?

Comment: @Veltro, thanks. just did

Comment: Simple test case where your code is not working: today is thursday, tomorrow is holiday. In this case you `getNextBsinessDay()` will return Sunday as next business day.

Comment: @TomaszPlaskota, good point, somehow the holidays are not working but I dont see why?

Comment: They are working correctly, it's just the logic inside that particular function that is flawed. You are only checking up to two days ahead, while you really should check indefinite number of days until you spot proper business day.

Comment: @TomaszPlaskota, but how should indefinite number of days look like? Insert anoter if statement will not work.

Comment: Sorry, was away. `while date.weekday(nextBusinessData) not in range(5) and nextBuinessData not in Holiday: nextBuinessData += timedelta(days=1)` instead of multiple `if`s

Comment: @TomaszPlaskota, thanks a lot and no worries. But I still have a problem with the dates. I made an example for the business date 02.04.2015 and add one day on it. I should receive 07.04.2015 because the 03.04.2015 is GoodFriday and the 06.04.2015 is EasterMonday.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148491/discussion-between-tomasz-plaskota-and-mcm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is final working solution

```
import datetime as dt
import holidays

Holiday = holidays.DE()

def getNextBusinessDay(date, n):
    for i in range(n):
        nextday = date1 + dt.timedelta(days=1)
        while nextday.weekday() > 4 or nextday in Holiday:
            nextday += dt.timedelta(days=1)
        date = nextday
    return date

#test
datetest = dt.datetime.strptime('02-04-15', '%d-%m-%y')
print(getNextBusinessDay(datetest,1))
```